# Which version of cl.exe does one use?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a bit of an unusual setup. I just have the compilers installed, and the sdk installed in a custom place. IN my /VC/bin folder, I have a cl.exe file. Also, I have a bunch of directories with other cl.exe compilers. I have been running the version VC/bin/cl.exe folder, but been getting some runtime error.

The error is `"the application was unable to start correctly".`

I'm thinking I might need to running one of the others? The other folders are:

```
[1033]
[amd64]
[ia64]
[x86_amd64]
[x86_ia64]
```

All these folders seem to have versions of the same files. Is it about my own architecture or the machine I am targeting's architecture?

I am running windows server 2008 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both. The AMD64 directory contains a compiler that runs on and targets AMD64. The IA64 directory likewise (runs on/targets IA64). The x86_XXX directories contain compilers that run on x86 and target the other architecture (AMD64 or IA64 respectively). At least if memory serves, the 1033 directory should contain the 32-bit compiler (i.e., runs on and targets x86).

To make things run correctly, your path needs the VC++ `bin` directory, then the SDK `bin` directory, then the VS `bin` directory.